# Google Analytics API: Where is the Analytics.builder method?

Tags: java, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics API with Java. I downloaded the latest version of the client library for the API and seem to have all the other packages I need. My problem is that the sample code Google provides as part of their [Analytics API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) uses the `Analytics.builder()` method (seen in the code below), but that method does not appear to be in the Analytics class. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
/*
 * Google Analytics API test.
 */
package helloanalyticsapi;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.*;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
//import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
//import com.google.api.services.oauth2.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 *
 * @author basset
 */
public class HelloAnalyticsApi {

    // Global instance of the HTTP transport.
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    // Global instance of the JSON factory.
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
        Credential credential = OAuth2Native.authorize(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new LocalServerReceiver(),
        Arrays.asList(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY));

        Analytics analytics;
        analytics = Analytics.builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
            .setApplicationName("Hello-Analytics-API-Sample")
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
            .build();

        return analytics;

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's been removed and you now have to replace that build chain with

`Analytics analytics = new Analytics(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)`

The tutorial is over a year old and appears not to have kept pace with the library.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Analytics.Builder() method in `com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics` I am using GA v3